# Get data from alias in Room Database android

Tags: android, android-room

How to get data from Query which has alias in it, in Room Database

Because we get data in Entity which only returns data in form of object so how can we get data from Query like this

```
SELECT *,(select count(uid) from UserTest) AS rec_count FROM UserTest
```

i.e. this fields data `rec_count`

> **Got Solution**

-

> **Step 1**

First Create new Pojo class, inside it write all the getter and setter written in your entity, and also include int getter and setter for your count value

> **Entity class:** UserTest.java

```
@Entity
public class UserTest {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "username")
    private String uname;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    @TypeConverters({DateConverter.class})
    private Date DATE;

    public UserTest() {
    }

    @Ignore
    public UserTest(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    @Ignore
    public UserTest(String uname, String imageUrl, Date DATE) {
        this.uname = uname;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.DATE = DATE;
    }

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Date getDATE() {
        return DATE;
    }

    public void setDATE(Date DATE) {
        this.DATE = DATE;
    }
}
```

> **New Pojo class:** Result.java

```
public class Result {

    private int rec_count;

    private int uid;

    private String username;

    private String image_url;

    @TypeConverters({DateConverter.class})
    private Date date;

    public Result() {
    }

    public Result(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }


    public Result(String uname, String imageUrl, Date DATE) {
        this.username = uname;
        this.image_url = imageUrl;
        this.date = DATE;
    }

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getImage_url() {
        return image_url;
    }

    public void setImage_url(String image_url) {
        this.image_url = image_url;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getRec_count() {
        return rec_count;
    }

    public void setRec_count(int rec_count) {
        this.rec_count = rec_count;
    }
}
```

> **Step 2:** Then in my Dao class i.e. UserDaoTest.java

Witten the query and set return type as

```
List<Result>
```

i.e.

```
@Query("SELECT *,(select count(uid) from UserTest) AS rec_count FROM UserTest")
    List<Result> getAllUsersData();
```

This worked for me!

> Explanation

Whenever we write a query in dao @Query anotation

in query if there is * it finds all column names inside your return pojo so we should include them all in your returning pojo

and for getting data in alias, we should also include getter and setter variable named on alias name in Returning Pojo class

**Hope this info will be helpful for others too!**

Comment: Create a POJO that models the result set, including an `int` or `long` for `rec_count`, and have that be the type you use for the `@Query`-annotated method. A `@Query` is not limited to returning just objects annotated with `@Entity`. You might have to expand the `*` into the desired list of columns, though. And note that every one of your objects will have the same value for `rec_count`, which is a little bit odd.

Comment: is there any solution such that we don't need to create an object for `rec_count` in Pojo and we still can get value of alias, because i have tried adding new object in pojo for alias it works but it also creates new column named `rec_count` in database

Comment: "it also creates new column named rec_count in database" -- that means that you put the field on your `@Entity`. Do not do that. Create a *separate* POJO -- without an `@Entity` annotation -- to use for the return values from the `@Query` method that you are trying to create. See [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/blob/v0.8/General/RoomDao/stuff/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/room/dao/StuffStore.java#L42-L43) and [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/blob/v0.8/General/RoomDao/stuff/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/room/dao/CustomerStats.java).

Comment: @CommonsWare ok will try it, thanks for helping though

Comment: @CommonsWare got solution see the solution, i have updated the question